# What are the restriction on the functions to define its Fourier transform?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Say, we define Fourier transform:

$$\tilde f(p)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}z f(z)e^{-ipz}$$

and the inverse transform

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}p~ \tilde f (p) e^{ipz}$$

Are these only defined for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or can it also be defined for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{C})$?

Is there a way to define an equivalent transform for complex functions by defining the integral over some contours instead of the real lines?

Comment: Define $L^1(\mathbb{C})$.  Is that the space of complex functions of a real variable such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\,dx<\infty$?

Comment: @MarkViola. The post talks about "contours" so I suppose that the domain is $\mathbb C.$

Comment: @MarkViola yeah I am asking about when the domain is $\mathbb{C}$